# Determine if application was launched from AppleScript

Tags: cocoa, applescript

Is it possible to determine if application was launched from AppleScript or just by clicking the icon in Cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be very surprised if this actually was possible.

AppleScript is just a scripting language, meaning that its capabilities are somewhat limited as far as applications go.

So I'd say you're probably out of luck (sorry :( ).